# Which settings in services.msc affect device location?

Tags: windows-10, location-services

I've had my Surface on "lockdown" (by altering settings personally) and changed something to prevent location detection on it. But I will now be using it out of the house and wish to have the "find my device" option. This is sadly greyed-out. I'm 99% sure it's something I've turned off in the past since I just kept it at home.
Additionally when I click the Find My Device is off -> Change button, Settings crashes (the window disappears).

Additionally, I tried turning Geolocation Service on, but when I hit OK it says "The system cannot find the file specified".

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “lockdown”?  Third-part software or built-in feature?  Edit your question

Comment: Like @Ramhound says, we'll have to know what you did to the computer to begin to have an idea how to fix it.

Comment: I altered everything myself, all in services.msc to keep privacy to a maximum.

Answer (score 0):

**> But I will now be using it out of the house and wish to have the "find my device" option. This is sadly greyed-out.**
Make sure that you had logged on system using **Microsoft Account**. You can check the details via Action Center – All settings - Accounts